# basic Fancybox/jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to add some simple image functionality to my fancybox gallery, but i'm getting a weird error.

I grabbed code provided here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq, looked at it through codepen, and added it to the jquery.fancybox.js file.

It works fine in codepen, but when I add it to my file I get an "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function" error.

I am kinda new to this jQuery stuff so any help will be appreciated.

this is the code i am trying to implement.

```
$( '[data-fancybox="images"]' ).fancybox({
infobar : false,
caption : function( instance, item ) {
    var caption = $(this).data('caption') || '';

    return ( caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '' ) + 'Image <span data-fancybox-index></span> of <span data-fancybox-count></span>';
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Make certain you have included jQuery and the fancybox jQuery min file in your project file per the Setup section of fancy box

Comment: you can download those or link via the CDN. I usually prefer the CDN, but ymmv

Comment: I made sure all of the files are placed correctly (it looks like some were out of order).  I added the codepen code at the bottom of the jquery.fancybox.js file here:
//START CUSTOM JS 
//END CUSTOM JS
})(document, window.jQuery || jQuery);

correct?

Comment: so best practice is not mod the vendor code file, but to make your own scripts.js file or whatever you want to call it, and add your custom scripts in that then make sure you link to jQuery then fancybox js then your custom scripts file